# Setting column to true/false based on comparison of two other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I want to compare column value and predicted, if they match then I want to set the value of a column "provided" to False. I'm having difficulty doing this.

Here's my data:

```
    ticker  periodDate  value   predicted
0   ibm     2017    150079.080  150079.080
1   ibm     2016    49799.140   49799.140
2   ibm     2015    459.016     45949.016
```

I want a new column to just have a True/False if value and predicted match. I tried this but to no avail:

```
def provideOrPredicted(df):
  if df['value'] == df['predicted']:
    df['provided'] = False
  elif df['value'] != df['predicted']:
    df['provided'] = False
  print(df)

provideOrPredicted(MergedDF)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Are you just after `df['provided'] = df['value'] == df['predicted']` ?

Comment: @JonClements no, I want the entire columns and data. I just want a new column to show if the columns match.

Comment: oh wait..I think you weren't asking a question but giving me a answer. lol. let me try that.

Comment: @JonClements your answer helped me, can you post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: JonClements, no pandas doesn't vectorize '==' or '!='. Also the OP wanted '!=' instead of '=='. So the solution is `df['provided'] = (df['value'].ne(df['predicted']))`

Comment: @smci I tried to use != and it worked. I manually reviewed the data and it seems to do what I want it to do. Why do you think it won't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, below line will check each row and boolean result will be assigned into the new column of `provided` as:

```
 df['provided'] = df['value'] == df['predicted']
```

Answer (score -2):

Because [the result of your `==`/`!=` comparisons is vectorized.
(or equivalently `df['value'].ne(df['predicted'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)

But the base-Python `if` command knows nothing about pandas and numpy, so it can't handle vectors (only scalars like 'True' and 'False').

So do the (vectorized) assignment directly in pandas, without any if-statement:

```
df['provided'] = df['value'].ne(df['predicted'])
```

Comment: (I totally revised the answer thanks to the correction from @Anakhand)